# 3D inverse transformation jacobian

Tags: transformation, 3d, robotics

I am working on robotics and I have to deal with transformations. In my case, $\pmb{t} = \left[x \; y \; z \; \psi \; \theta \; \phi \right]^T$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ is the translation and $\psi$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the roll, pitch and yaw angles. I my case I apply the rotations as $\pmb{R}=\mathrm{\bf{Rot}}_z(\phi)\mathrm{\bf{Rot}}_y(\theta)\mathrm{\bf{Rot}}_x(\psi)$. In [Neira 1993](http://webdiis.unizar.es/GRPTR/pubs/Neira_PHDtesis_1993.pdf) and [Smith 1990](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8997-2_14) the inverse of the transformation is defined:

$\pmb{t}' = \ominus \pmb{t} = \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \\  \psi' \\ \theta' \\ \phi' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\pmb{R}^T\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} \\  \mathrm{atan2}(o_z,a_z) \\ \mathrm{atan2}(-n_z,n_x\cos(\phi)+n_y\sin(\phi)) \\ \mathrm{atan2}(n_y,n_x) \end{bmatrix}$

where:

$\pmb{R} = \begin{bmatrix} n_x & o_x & a_x \\ n_y & o_y & a_y \\ n_z & o_z & a_z \end{bmatrix}$

In the same works, the jacobians of this operation is described:

$ \pmb{J}_\ominus = \begin{bmatrix} -\pmb{R}^T & \pmb{N} \\ \pmb{0}_{3\times3} & \pmb{Q} \end{bmatrix}$

with:

$\pmb{N} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -n_z x \cos(\phi)-n_zy\sin(\phi)+z\cos(\theta) & n_y x-n_x y\\z' & -o_z x \cos(\phi) - o_z y \sin(\phi) + z \sin(\theta) \sin(\psi) & o_y x - o_x y \\ -y' & a_z x \cos(\phi) - a_z y \sin(\phi) + z \sin(\theta) \cos(\psi) & a_y x - a_x y \end{bmatrix}$
$\pmb{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} -n_x/(1-a_x^2) & -o_x \cos(\psi)/(1-a_x^2) & a_z a_x / (1 - a_x^2) \\ o_x/(1-a_x^2)^{1/2} & -a_z \cos(\phi) / (1-a_x^2)^{1/2} & a_y/(1-a_x^2)^{1/2} \\ n_x a_x /(1-a_x^2) & -a_y \cos(\phi) /(1-a_x^2) & -a_z /(1-a_x^2) \end{bmatrix}$

I have implemented this function and its Jacobian (code is available [here](https://github.com/apalomer/spatial_relationships)) as well as the direct compounding operation ($\pmb{t}_3 = \pmb{t}_1\oplus\pmb{t}_2$). Then, I have also implemented a way to compute the derivatives of each function using [Ceres-Solver](http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html). Then, I compare the Jacobian that I implemented from [Neira 1993](http://webdiis.unizar.es/GRPTR/pubs/Neira_PHDtesis_1993.pdf) and [Smith 1990](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8997-2_14) with the one computed using [Ceres-Solver](http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html). The Jacobian of the transformation from the analytic and the automatic differentiation is very similar (numerical error differences). However, the inverse composition there is a difference between the analytic Jacobian from [Neira 1993](http://webdiis.unizar.es/GRPTR/pubs/Neira_PHDtesis_1993.pdf) with the one computed using [Ceres-Solver](http://ceres-solver.org/automatic_derivatives.html). Moreover, these two jacobians are different only 50% (approximately) of the times and always in the same elements of the Jacobian, row 2 of $\pmb{Q}$. You can test the code (it is developed with Ubuntu, I do not know if it will compile in windows).

Does anybody have an idea of where can I get the Jacobian of the inverse of the transformation (a part from [Neira 1993](http://webdiis.unizar.es/GRPTR/pubs/Neira_PHDtesis_1993.pdf) and [Smith 1990](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8997-2_14)) or point me what is wrong with the current Jacobian?

Comment: The Jacobian of the inverse is the inverse of the Jacobian.

Comment: So you would compute the inverse of the jacobian $J_\oplus$ for $\pmb{0}_{6\times1}\oplus\pmb{t}$?

Comment: Thank you for the great work, first of all. I saw a commit in your repository, declaring the resolution of inverse composition jacobian issue. You implement Smith approach in that commit. However, when I tried running tests neither Neira not Smith fails. Did you manage to fix Neira approach too?

Comment: If that's indeed resolved, maybe worth to add an answer here too.

Comment: I think the way it is implemented in the attached repo is right. I tested it using [gradient checker from ceres-solver](https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/1.12.0/include/ceres/gradient_checker.h) (it checks the given jacobian with the numerical derivative)